# Why kernel's arm64 vector table is aligned with 11?

Tags: assembly, arm64

In [arch/arm64/kernel/entry.s](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/kernel/entry.S), vector table is aligned with 11.

```
    .align  11
ENTRY(vectors)
    kernel_ventry   1, sync_invalid         // Synchronous EL1t
    kernel_ventry   1, irq_invalid          // IRQ EL1t
    kernel_ventry   1, fiq_invalid          // FIQ EL1t
    kernel_ventry   1, error_invalid        // Error EL1t

    kernel_ventry   1, sync             // Synchronous EL1h
    kernel_ventry   1, irq              // IRQ EL1h
    kernel_ventry   1, fiq_invalid          // FIQ EL1h
    kernel_ventry   1, error            // Error EL1h

    kernel_ventry   0, sync             // Synchronous 64-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, irq              // IRQ 64-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, fiq_invalid          // FIQ 64-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, error            // Error 64-bit EL0

#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT
    kernel_ventry   0, sync_compat, 32      // Synchronous 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, irq_compat, 32       // IRQ 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, fiq_invalid_compat, 32   // FIQ 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, error_compat, 32     // Error 32-bit EL0
#else
    kernel_ventry   0, sync_invalid, 32     // Synchronous 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, irq_invalid, 32      // IRQ 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, fiq_invalid, 32      // FIQ 32-bit EL0
    kernel_ventry   0, error_invalid, 32        // Error 32-bit EL0
#endif
END(vectors)
```

And in other codes such as [linux-kernel-module-cheat](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/2cfdbf79f2708fd6bf57423a77a1c4995c846999/lkmc/aarch64.h) is aligned with 11.
But I know aarch64 is aligned with 0x80 https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100933/0100/AArch64-exception-vector-table.

Why they use 11byte align?

Comment: Sorry. I forget arm64 is first aligned with  0x800. This is equivalent to 2^11

Comment: IMO, never use `.align`, always `.balign 0x800` or `.p2align 11` to avoid ambiguity of whether `.align` means `.balign` or `.p2align`.  (Especially relevant with things like `4` vs. `2^4 = 16` - `.balign 11` would be an error because 11-byte alignment is literally impossible: alignment only makes sense as a multiple of a power of 2.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, that's architecture requirements for ARMv8, you just need to accept and live with it.

Addresses of vector tables (for each EL level) are written into special **Vector Base Address Register**-s, namely `VBAR_EL3`, `VBAR_EL2`, `VBAR_EL1`.

Each register is:

- `Bits [63:11] - Vector Base Address`
- `Bits [10:0] - Reserved, RES0`

So you simply could not provide address not aligned to 2^11.

Refer "ARMv8 Architecture Reference Manual"

PS: `0x80` are beginning of different kind of interrupts for given Exception Level (ELx)